# A question of Probability theory

Tags: probability-theory

A has 3 shares in a Lottery in which there are 3 prizes and 6 blanks. B has 1 share in a lottery in which there are 1 prize and 2 blanks. Show that A's chance of success to B's is 16/7.

Comment: Do you mean: "A's chance of success *divided by* B's chance of success"?

Comment: Take a look at [How to ask a good question at Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). To avoid downvotes and closing you should add your own efforts to the question, and tell us where you got stuck.

Comment: Yes you get it @MattiP.

Comment: Maybe you can try calculating the individual success probabilities, first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define what you mean by success. Here it means having at least one winning lottery ticket.
I hope you are familiar with the concept of Permutations and Combinations and how to calculate them.

A will be successful in 3 scenarios:
1. he has 1 winning ticket and 2 blanks
2. he has 2 winning tickets and 1 blank
3. he has 3 winning tickets

Thus, the probability that A is successful
$$ P(A) = \frac{{3 \choose 1}{6 \choose 2} + {3 \choose 2}{6 \choose 1} + {3 \choose 3}{6 \choose 0}}{{9 \choose 3}} $$
$$ P(A) = \frac{3*15 + 3*6 + 1*1}{84} $$
$$ P(A) = \frac{64}{84} = \frac{16}{21} $$

Similarly, the probability that B is successful
$$ P(B) = \frac{1}{3} $$

Hence we have proved that P(A)/P(B) = 16/7